# .equals never evaluates to true in processing

Tags: string, if-statement, processing, equals

I have programmed an Engduino to measure temperature in the room using it's thermistor and output the values to the Serial port; when the program begins, it outputs "start temp" and when the program ends it outputs "end temp", and in between it outputs the temperature value every 2 seconds. I'm using .readString in Processing to read these values as they're being measured.

```java
String str = myEngduino.readString();
 if(str!=null){
    println(str);
}
```

This code works fine and the values being printed to the console are indeed "start temp", then the temperatures as they're read, then "end temp" when the program finishes. So I don't understand why the if statement in this code never evaluates to true:

```java
String str = myEngduino.readString();
if(str!=null){
    println(str);
    if(str.equals("start temp")){
      println("START");
    }
}
```

str is definitely set to "start temp" because it is printed out to the console, so why won't my if statement evaluate to true at this point?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend double checking if `readString()` returns the new line character(`\n`)  as well.

You can try to use [trim()](https://processing.org/reference/trim_.html):

```
String str = myEngduino.readString();
if(str!=null){
    str = str.trim();
    println(str);
    if(str.equals("start temp")){
      println("START");
    }
}
```

Another workaround I can think of is checking if str.[contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) instead of `equals()`